# ZSH `rvm-prompt` on RHS prompt not refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, zsh, zshrc

I have `rvm-prompt` feeding into my RPrompt, however it is not refreshing between commands: [image: rvm-prompt and rprompt out of sync] ([Larger image](https://img.skitch.com/20110726-te88bucw84himfi6b6q561216p.jpg))

For example, when I cd from one ruby project to another with an .rvmrc file pointing to a new gemset, the rprompt simply will not refresh. It appears that it must be caching the rprompt for performance purposes, so I am curious as to how I can force a refresh for zsh at each command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you generate the prompt? I do it like this:

```
local rvm_ruby=' %{$fg[red]%}[$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt i v g s)]%{$reset_color%}'
```

And then use the `rvm_ruby` variable in my prompt:

```
PROMPT="${user_host}${directory}${git_branch}${rvm_ruby}%B
→%b "
```

EDIT: Note that the place where you create the contents for the variable needs single quotes, otherwise the command will get substituted right away and not updated anymore. This initially took me a bit to figure out. You may have the same problem defining your RHS prompt.

Comment: The key here is simply the *single quotes*.  I did not realize that that was the case!  Thanks.

Comment: Also found you need to call `setopt promptsubst` when prompts weren't being substituted